# Why do I get a "too many values to unpack" error with Python's split function?

Tags: python, string

I have a python function that must read data from file and split it into two key and value, and then store it in dictionary. Example:
file:

```
http://google.com 2
http://python.org 3
# and so on a lot of data
```

I use the split function for it, but when there is really a lot of data it raises value error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

What can I do about this ?

This is the exact code that fails

```
with open(urls_file_path, "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        url, count = line.split()# fails here
        url_dict[url] = int(count)
```

Comment: Can you please show the exact line of code, in which this error is thrown?

Comment: You do something wrong. (Sorry, but without seeing what you do, I cannot provide a better answer.)

Comment: It essentially means you are not handling cases when there is more than one space in the input string.

Comment: Can you give us a more extensive sample of your code, because I believe in one line you might have `url number number` or something like that.

Comment: Expanding on what @GamesBrainiac said: Give us a complete running example of both code and input data, stripped down as far as possible to still demonstrate the error. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details.

Comment: there cant be mistakes in file

Comment: @user3156971 And Python has been tested/used very well, so it can't be  wrong :)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich If it was `life` instead of `file` :p

Comment: @user3156971 well, there can't be anything else that could go wrong!

Comment: @user3156971: Out of curiosity, do you work for Westworld, Jurassic Park, or just an insurance company?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are trying to unwrap the split list in to these two variables.

```
url, count = line.split()
```

What if there is no space or two or more spaces? Where will the rest of the words go?

```
data = "abcd"
print data.split()    # ['abcd']
data = "ab cd"
print data.split()    # ['ab', 'cd']
data = "a b c d"
print data.split()    # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

You can actually check the length before assigning

```
with open(urls_file_path, "r") as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        split_list = line.split()
        if len(split_list) != 2:
            raise ValueError("Line {}: '{}' has {} spaces, expected 1"
                .format(idx, line.rstrip(), len(split_list) - 1))
        else:
            url, count = split_list
            print url, count
```

With the input file,

```
http://google.com 2
http://python.org 3
http://python.org 4 Welcome
http://python.org 5
```

This program produces,

```
$ python Test.py
Read Data: http://google.com 2
Read Data: http://python.org 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 6, in <module>
    .format(idx, line.rstrip(), len(split_list) - 1))
ValueError: Line 3: 'http://python.org 4 Welcome' has 2 spaces, expected 1
```

Following [@abarnert's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254645/python-split-function-too-many-values-to-unpack-error/21254804?noredirect=1#comment32020747_21254804), you can use `partition` function like this

```
url, _, count = data.partition(" ")
```

If there are more than one spaces/no space, then `count` will hold rest of the string or empty string, respectively.

**If you are using Python 3.x,** you can do something like this

```
first, second, *rest = data.split()
```

First two values will be assigned in `first` and `second` respectively and the rest of the list will be assigned to `rest`, in Python 3.x

Comment: He might also want `url, count = line.split(None, 1)` (which will handle any extra spaces by dumping them into `count`), or `url, _, count = line.partition(' ')` (which will do likewise, but will also handle no spaces by leaving `count` empty). Or he might just want to catch this exception and re-raise a more relevant one, because `'a b c d'` should count as an error but hopefully a more debuggable one. Or maybe none of the above; it's hard to tell given the little we have to go on…

Comment: @abarnert Thanks :) I added the `partition` method in the answer and raising `ValueError` now.

Comment: Note that he currently thinks that such things can't happen in his file, so I would advise using a method that complains loudly with line number and data on that line, and not one that just swallows everything silently.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich That makes sense. Updated the code to throw an error when the split returns more/less than 2

Comment: @thefourtheye: The OP's code already raises an error, which is exactly what he's complaining about. I think what Remco was saying (and what I meant by "re-raise a more relevant one") was to pack in more information, like `line 2137 ("http://bad url 17") has 2 spaces, expected 1`.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for clarifying :) I updated my code to throw an error message, exactly like that :)

Comment: @thefourtheye: Your answer is now so nice that it's almost a shame that nothing can possibly ever be wrong in the OP's input data. :)

Comment: You should also first mention the `split(... maxsplit=n)` argument, it's simpler and better-known.

Answer (score 0):

Too many values to unpack error will come when number of identifier on left side of your split expression is less than the number of seperator(here blank space) in the line, so you have to keep exact number of identifiers on left for assignment of expression after splitting by your seperator

Comment: When answering a 7 year old question with a comprehensive, accepted answer, please ensure that your answer doesn't just cover points that were made in earlier answers.

Answer (score 0):

The "too many values to unpack" error can also be returned by the `str.split` method of pandas data frames.

For example splitting a character vector on the "`,`" pattern:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"x": ["a", "a, b", "a,b,c"]})
df.x.str.split(",")

# 0          [a]
# 1      [a,  b]
# 2    [a, b, c]


df.x.str.split(",", n=1)

# 0         [a]
# 1     [a,  b]
# 2    [a, b,c]


df.x.str.split(",", expand=True)

#    0     1     2
# 0  a  None  None
# 1  a     b  None
# 2  a     b     c

df.x.str.split(",", n=1, expand=True)

#    0     1
# 0  a  None
# 1  a     b
# 2  a   b,c
```

The following version works only if each row has exactly 2 splits. It fails with the error “too many values to unpack (expected 2)” in this example

```
df["y"], df["z"] = df.x.str.split(",", n=1)
```

The last version with both `n=1` and `expand=True` is the one to use for multiple vector assignment. It is equivalent to [tidyr::separate](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) in R.

```
df[["y", "z"]] = df.x.str.split(",", n=1, expand=True)
df

#        x  y     z
# 0      a  a  None
# 1   a, b  a     b
# 2  a,b,c  a   b,c
```

According to the [documentation of
pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)
If n > 0 and

> "If for a certain row the number of found splits < n, append None for padding
> up to n if expand=True."