# ValueError in Python: Too many values to unpack

Tags: python, valueerror

I'm getting a valueError on the below code.

```
ValueError('too many values to unpack',)
```

```py
with open('38374657484839373636.csv') as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        if line:
            repo, file, pkey = line.split(",")
            keys.add(pkey)
```

Comment: Evidently there are more than two commas in at least one of your lines. Have you considered using Python's built in CSV handling module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string only by first space in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636248/split-a-string-only-by-first-space-in-python), just use `split(... maxsplit=n)` argument. And if you want to see a more complicated answer, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21254804/202229)

Comment: Thanks, got it now - apologies didn't see the other thread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to read CSV-files (and Excel-files too with `pd.read_excel()`) is to use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('38374657484839373636.csv')
df.head()
```

Sometimes it is necessary to set the delimiter explicitly, depending on what's in our input file. E.g, if the delimiter in your file is `/`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('38374657484839373636.csv', delimiter='/')
df.head()
```

Watch also wether your csv-file has a header or not. E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('38374657484839373636.csv', delimiter='/',header=None)
df.head()
```